# How can I get "find" output so that I can copy and paste it to other commands?

Tags: command-line, unix, find

Is it possible to print `find` output paths in such a way that you can copy and paste them, they will already be properly escaped so that you can execute commands on that path? Usually I have to put quotes around them.

Example.

```
$ find -iname "*Resume 2004*doc~"
./Career/No Longer Needed/Microsoft Resume 2004.doc
$ rm ./Career/No Longer Needed/Microsoft Resume 2004.doc
ERROR: No such file: ./Career/No
$ rm "./Career/No Longer Needed/Microsoft Resume 2004.doc"
```

Note: I do not want to execute the `rm` "automatically" via `-exec` or `xargs`. I know how to do that.

Comment: Which shell do you have?

Comment: zsh. Does that make a difference? I'd hope there is a shell independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

`find` have an `-exec` argument.

If you are trying to delete `find` output, just use this command:

```
find -iname "*Resume 2004*doc~" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Not the answer to my question, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The `rm` command doesn't work since your filename includes white spaces, so for this reason you either have to quote your file, or you can use backslash without quoting, like that:

```
rm ./Career/No\ Longer\ Needed/Microsoft\ Resume\ 2004.doc
```

So, you cannot really print the path and delete it by copy pasting because you either need to add quotes or backslashes, but what you can do is to print the `inode` of the file as well with the `find` command and delete it by using the inode number like that:

```
find . -type f -name "*Resume 2004*doc~" -printf '%p %i\n'
```

and you get back its inode lets say 1234567 and you delete it like that:

```
find . -inum 1234567 -exec rm -fi {} \;
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know inodes could be useful this way. I wonder if there's a way to remove a file without re-executing `find -inum`. A quick Google search suggests not :( Since you have to use `-exec` you might as well execute `rm` directly as in the other solution.